# Binary search implementation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

Please, I came across this code that implements binary search but when I tried changing some things in it, I was getting results I didn't expect. Here's the code:

```
 function binary_search(list, lo, hi, key){
 var mid;

if (lo > hi)
{
    console.log("Key not found\n");
    return;
}
mid = Math.floor((lo + hi) / 2);
if (list[mid] == key)
{
    console.log("Key found\n");
    //return mid;  Expected this to return the index where the key was found 
   //but it returns undefined...
}
else if (list[mid] > key)
{
    binary_search(list, lo, mid - 1, key);
}
else if (list[mid] < key)
{
    binary_search(list, mid + 1, hi, key);
}
}

binary_search([1,3,5,6,7,9],0,5,1)// logs 'Key found' to the console(working correctly);
```

When I tried changing up some things in the code(which is shown in the commented portion of the code above) I get an unexpected result but I don't know WHY. And again what is the need of checking `if (lo > hi)` since `hi` should, as I think, always have a higher value than `lo`. Would `hi` ever be lower than `lo`? Can someone please make these things clear to me?

Comment: Within the two `else` clauses, you need to `return binary_search(...)`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much. I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```js
function binarySearch(arr, num, l, r){
 if( arr instanceof Array ){
   
    l = isNaN(l) ? 0 : l;
    r = isNaN(r) ? arr.length - 1: r;
    let mid = l + 1 + Math.round((r - l)/2 - 1);    
    console.log(l, r, mid, arr[mid]);
    
    if( num == arr[mid] ){ 
     console.log("found"); 
      return mid; 
    }
    
    if( typeof arr[mid] == "undefined" || l == r ){
     console.log("not found"); return -1;
    }
    
    if( num < arr[mid] ){  
     console.log("take left"); 
      return binarySearch(arr, num, l, r - mid);
    }
    
    console.log("take right");
    return binarySearch(arr, num, mid, r);
    
  }
}

console.log( binarySearch([0, 0, 1 ,1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 11], 2) );
```